# Iterating over table using Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to angular and js. I did a table  (just a header) and a button. When I click the button a new row line is added. Every cell of that row is a form text field. Everithing works fine. Now I'm trying to do a second button, when I click it must iterate over the rows and validate the fields. I'm not finding any documentation about that... so i'm not sure if this mettod (add a new row with a button) is appropiate. That's how I did it:

index.html this contains angular and my script, also contains the routes:

```
<html ng-app="assets">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sources/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var assets = angular.module('assets', ['ngRoute']);

            assets.config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'home.html'
                }).
                when('/:tipusactius', {
                    templateUrl: 'tipusactius.html',
                    controller: 'TipusActiusCtrl'
                }).
                when('/:tipusactius/alta', {
                    templateUrl: 'tipusactius-alta.html',
                    controller: 'AfegirTipusActiusCtrl'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
            });


            assets.controller('TipusActiusCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
                $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.tipus_actius = data;
                });

                // Ordena taula per id desc
                $scope.sortField = 'idtipus_actius';
                $scope.reverse = false;
            });

            assets.controller('AfegirTipusActiusCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

                    // Camps formulari text pla
                    $scope.nomAtribut = "<input type='text' name='firstname'>";
                    $scope.mida = "<input type='number' name='firstname'>";
                    $scope.obligatori = "<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='yes'>";

                    // Construeix combo
                    $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/getCombo/1').success(function(data) {
                        $scope.options = data;
                    });

                    $scope.atributs = [];
                    $scope.addField = function() {
                        $scope.atributs.push($scope.atributs.length);
                    };

                    $scope.prioritat = $scope.atributs.length;
            });

            assets.directive('compile', compile);

            function compile($compile)
            {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    replace: true,
                    link: linkFunction
                };

                function linkFunction(scope, element, attrs)
                {
                    scope.$watch(
                        function (scope)
                        {
                            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                        },
                        function (value)
                        {
                            element.html(value);

                            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }

            </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the view where the table is(tipusactius-alta):

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8" ng-controller="AfegirTipusActiusCtrl">
            <button ng-click="addField()">Nou atribut</button>
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nom atribut</td>
                        <td>Tipus</td>
                        <td>Mida</td>
                        <td>Prioritat</td>
                        <td>Obligatori</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="atribut in atributs">
                        <td compile="nomAtribut"></td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="tipus">
                                <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.idvalors_combo}}">{{option.valor}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td compile="mida"></td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="prioritat">
                                <option ng-repeat="p in prioritat" value="{{p}}">{{p}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td compile="obligatori"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this has been a good idea. I would like to find a way to iterate over the rows to read cell values, and if the values of all cells from all the rows is ok submit the values to the web service but I have no idea. Any help will be great.

Comment: Are all cells editable all the time?

Comment: Yes, are editable all time

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to manipulate html directly. Just use ng-repeat over your data collection. Button should add new items to that collection and angular will create new table row in the document.

I've created small sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/252/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('tableCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.dataTable = [{
    "name": "Alex",
    "lastName": "Karlov",
    "age": 23,
    "sex": 1
  }];


  $scope.options = [{
    "value": 1,
    "title": "Male"
  }, {
    "value": 2,
    "title": "Female"
  }];


  $scope.addRow = function() {
    var newItem = {
      name: "",
      lastName: "",
      age: "",
      sex: ""
    }
    $scope.dataTable.push(newItem);
  };

});
```

And this is the html (I've created it based on yours code):

```
<div class="col-md-8" ng-controller="tableCtrl">
  <button ng-click="addRow()">Add row</button>
  <div>
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Sex</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in dataTable">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.lastName" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="item.age" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <select ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options" ng-model="item.sex"></select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In that sample I've put all my data into dataTable variable. When I want to add one more row, I just need to add new empty object (or with predefined values) into dataTable collection. Angular will do the trick.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But then how can I read am the rows and operate with it? I'm very lost about

Comment: You can iterate over dataTable (in my example) to do any type of processing. Give me example of your scenario and I will try to illustrate them. You can just send your entire data table to server, or perform validation, or some other word.

Comment: Yes, but I think I didn't explain myself very well. There are 5 columns (2 select fields, 1 text fields, 1 number field and 1 checkbox) will work appropriate? Your idea looks a lot more reasonable than mine

Comment: Ok thank you I'm reading this from my phone and I don't see well the code. Im gonna try your solution. I will tell you about